# Не парсится XML в iOS

Tags: ios, xml, modx

Всем привет. Недавно переносил сайт компании по созданию 3D панорам c Джумлы на MODX Revo. Так вот. На странице http://www.volkswagen.com.ua/about/ подгружается панорама с их сайта objects360.com. При заходе с устройств на iOS содержимое 3Д панорамы на этой странице http://www.volkswagen.com.ua/about/ не отображается.

Пишет **FATAL ERROR -** *путь к xml файлу* - **loading or parsing failed.**

И это только на iOS. На андроидах и ПК все отлично работает. В чем может быть проблема?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых панорама запускается во Flash Player он не поддерживается на iOS устройствах, в связи своей убогости второго.
Во-вторых возможно запускается как выяснилось  понорама на WebGL  и вот она то и не может распарсить XML. Здесь вопрос не в iOS, а в ручках JS программиста.

Comment: зайдите с iOS по этой ссылке http://objects360.com/projects/virtual-tours/kfc-novus и убедитесь что флеш работает

Comment: Зашел и уебидлся что это WebGL. Так что конигурируйте плагин krpano.com

Comment: Отключил плагин флеша в хроме и ваша ссылка http://www.volkswagen.com.ua/about/ пишет что не может распарсить XML

Comment: @Bimawa, то есть нужно обратиться к программисту, который делал эти панорамы чтобы он конфиги настроил?

Comment: Незнаю, выводы делайте сами. Я просто методом тыка могу подитожить что панорама написаная на WebGL, по каким-то причинам не может разпарсить XML.